# How to use Boolean input in Arcgis with arpy? (Desktop edition)

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, boolean

So, my code goes something like this:

```
haveopenvel = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(10)
arcpy.AddMessage(haveopenvel)
if (haveopenvel == True):#error
    openvelftsec = Raster(openvelftsec)
    arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(openvelftsec,"openvelftsec","#",ext,"#")
else:
    ##Optional Model that can be
```

However, the loop always goes into the else loop even when I check mark the input in the tool. COuld anyone tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: The user is entering the text `True`? Then you need `if (haveopenvel == 'True')`

Comment: Replace `arcpy.GetParameterAsText(10)` with `arcpy.GetParameter(10)`.

Comment: Tried the change....still going in the else loop. No the user is clicking a radio button.